# Api Request being routed to the Frontend port 3000 instead of Backend 5000

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux

I have setup an Express Backend server with a React Frontend server. I have also setup an actions file in Redux to make a request to the api server to fetch data. Here's what the actions file looks like:

```
import axios from 'axios';

import {REGISTER_SUCCESS, 
    REGISTER_FAIL, 
    USER_LOADED, 
    AUTH_ERROR,
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_FAIL} from './types';

import {setAlert} from './alert';

import setAuthToken from '../utils/setAuthToken';

//Load User
export const loadUser = () => async dispatch => {
    if(localStorage.token) {
        setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
    }

    try {
        const res = await axios.get('/api/auth');

        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOADED,
            payload: res.data
        });

    } catch(err) {
        dispatch({
            type: AUTH_ERROR
        });
    }
}

//Register User

export const register = ({name, email, password}) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
    }

    const body = JSON.stringify({name, email, password});

    try {
        const res = await axios.post('/api/users', body, config);

        dispatch({
            type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        });
        dispatch(loadUser());
    } catch(err) {
        const errors = err.response.data.errors;
        if(errors) {
            errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
        }

        dispatch({
            type: REGISTER_FAIL
        });
    }
}

//Login User

export const login = ({email, password}) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
    }

    const body = JSON.stringify({email, password});

    try {
        const res = await axios.post('/api/auth', body, config);

        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        });
        dispatch(loadUser());
    } catch(err) {
        const errors = err.response.data.errors;
        if(errors) {
            errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
        }

        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAIL
        });
    }
}
```

Now when i load the web application in the browser, it should make a request to the api server on Port 5000. However, it is being router to the 3000 port (:3000/api/auth). It was working fine up till the Register action. The error happened after I inserted the Login action.

Here's the error:

*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)*

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Here's the Package.json file with the Proxy setup

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.1",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

Edit: Here's the Auth.js api code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require('../../middleware/auth');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('config');
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

const User = require('../../models/User');

//@route    GET api/auth
//@desc     Test route
//@access   Public
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
        res.json(user);
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
});

//@route    POST api/auth
//@desc     Authenticate user and get token
//@access   Public
router.post('/', 
[
    check('email', 'Please include a valid Email').isEmail(),
    check('password', 'Password is required').exists()
], 
async (req, res) => {
    //console.log(req.body);    //need to include body parser to get the data in the body
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const { email, password} = req.body;
    try {
        //See if user exists
        let user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: [{msg: 'Invalid Credentials'}] });
        }

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if(!isMatch) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: [{msg: 'Invalid Credentials'}] });
    }
        //Return Json webtoken
        const payload = {
            user: {
                id: user.id
            }
        };

        jwt.sign(payload, 
            config.get('jwtSecret'), 
            {expiresIn: 360000},
            (err, token) => {
                if(err) throw err;
                res.json({token});
            }
            );

    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Edit: Here's the terminal output:

```
[nodemon] 2.0.2
[0] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[0] [nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[0] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[0] [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[0] Server started on port 5000
[0] MongoDB connected
[1] i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.1.45/
[1] i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
[1] i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from E:\Web Projects\devconnector\client\public
[1] i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
[1] Starting the development server...
[1]
[1] Compiled successfully!
[1]
[1] You can now view client in the browser.
[1]
[1]   Local:            http://localhost:3000/
[1]   On Your Network:  http://192.168.1.45:3000/
[1]
[1] Note that the development build is not optimized.
[1] To create a production build, use npm run build.
[1]
[0] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[0] [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[0] Server started on port 5000
[0] MongoDB connected
```

Edit: Here's the middleware auth.js code:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('config');

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    //Get Token from Header
    const token = req.header('x-auth-token');

    //Check if not token
    if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'No token, authorization denied' });
    }

    //Verify Token
    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtSecret'));

        req.user = decoded.user;
        next();
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Token is not valid' });
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using webpack as a dev server for your front end? If so, you can set up a proxy in your configuration so you don't have to write absolute url paths like the posted answer suggests. Please post your config for webpack if you're using it and I'll help you sort it out.

Comment: Thanks. I am making an edit for you. The proxy was already setup, And it was working fine until I added the Login action code. It was working fine for the Register action.

Comment: I did get a proxy error in the terminal yesterday once but then it disappeared.

Comment: Hmmm, so now with your error code added to the post (401) it seems that it's stemming from your server - not react. Can you post the express code that handles requests to the `/api/auth` endpoint?

Comment: Sure thing. Making another edit.

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking your error lies in there - check your logs in your express terminal to find which section of the post request handler is returning `401` to your front end.

Comment: Actually there are no errors in the terminal. Check my latest edit.

Comment: Fair enough, but your front end is receiving a `401` unauthorized error code - so somewhere in that function body is a statement that is returns a status that means the credentials you're posting are not authorized to log in. If there aren't any logs telling you which statement is doing that, add some!

Comment: Actually I am following a course as a Beginner and I am having a hard time troubleshooting this issue. Could I send you the project files so you can take a look?

Comment: what's your middleware code?

Comment: Adding the Middleware code right now.

Comment: did you manage a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

The error is not in the frontend. The requests proxied by webpackdevserver happen in the background, the browser still thinks that it is communicating with :3000.

Checkout your Auth middleware, you might be rejecting requests from unauthenticated users.

Comment: I understand, but the relative path was working file until I inserted the Login action code. The register action was working fine.

Comment: Oh you added a ton more code, even with proxy, the network tab will always show 3000, the requests is proxied by webpack-dev-server. and your 401 error is coming from the server